# ** operator TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

I keep getting this error message:

```
File "/Users/SalamonCreamcheese/Documents/4.py", line 31, in <module>
    testFindRoot()
File "/Users/SalamonCreamcheese/Documents/4.py", line 29, in testFindRoot
    print " ", result**power, " ~= ", x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I don't understand why it's saying 
that `result**power` is of wrong type(s), I'm assuming it means string, and why that's an error.

```
def findRoot(x, power, epsilon):
    """Assumes x and epsilon int or float,power an int,
        epsilon > 0 and power >= 1
    Returns float y such that y**power is within epsilon of x
        If such a float does not exist, returns None"""
    if x < 0 and power % 2 == 0:
        return None
    low = min(-1.0, x)
    high = max(1,.0 ,x)
    ans = (high + low) / 2.0
    while abs(ans**power - x) > epsilon: 
        if ans**power < x:
            low = ans
        else:
            high = ans
        ans = (high +low) / 2.0
    return ans

def testFindRoot():
    for x in (0.25, -0.25, 2, -2, 8, -8):
        epsilon = 0.0001
        for power in range(1, 4):
            print 'Testing x = ' + str(x) +\
                  ' and power = ' + str(power)
            result = (x, power, epsilon)
            if result == None:
                print 'No result was found!'
            else:
                print " ", result**power, " ~= ", x

testFindRoot()
```

Comment: Apparently you don't realize that "type(s)" is just short for "type or types".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a mistake on this line:

```
result = (x, power, epsilon)
```

I suspect you want to be calling the `findroot` function with those three values as arguments rather than creating a tuple out of them. Try changing it to:

```
result = findroot(x, power, epsilon)
```

Answer (score 2):

`result**power` is trying to find `x to the y` where `x = result` and `y = power`.

Your problem is that `result` is a **tuple.** You can't raise a tuple to a power. It makes no sense...

You need to access the value inside the tuple that is supposed to be exponentiated and exponentiate that.

For instance, `result[0] ** power`, `result[1] ** power`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you meant to call `findRoot` with the three arguments `x`, `power`, and `epsilon`. Try editing the line

```
result = (x, power, epsilon)
```

to be

```
result = findRoot(x, power, epsilon)
```

As that line presently is, `result` is not a number (which you'd want for the `**` operator). `result` a tuple that has three different objects in it: `x`, `power`, and `epsilon`. You can use the `**` operator on any two of the items in `result` but it's not defined for the `tuple` type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a powers operation to a tuple. If you need to have all of the values to that power, try operating them separately.

You might need:
[power**n for n in result]