# FindRootTest not working

Tags: python

```
File "/Users/SalamonCreamcheese/Documents/4.py", line 31, in <module>
    testFindRoot()
File "/Users/SalamonCreamcheese/Documents/4.py", line 29, in testFindRoot
    print " ", result**power, " ~= ", x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I don't understand why it's saying that result** power is of type(s), Im I'm assuming meaning string, and why thatsthat's an error. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

```
def findRoot(x, power, epsilon):
    """Assumes x and epsilon int or float,power an int,
        epsilon > 0 and power >= 1
    Returns float y such that y**power is within epsilon of x
        If such a float does not exist, returns None"""
    if x < 0 and power % 2 == 0:
        return None
    low = min(-1.0, x)
    high = max(1,.0 ,x)
    ans = (high + low) / 2.0
    while abs(ans**power - x) > epsilon: 
        if ans**power < x:
            low = ans
        else:
            high = ans
        ans = (high +low) / 2.0
    return ans

def testFindRoot():
    for x in (0.25, -0.25, 2, -2, 8, -8):
        epsilon = 0.0001
        for power in range(1, 4):
            print 'Testing x = ' + str(x) +\
                  ' and power = ' + str(power)
            result = (x, power, epsilon)
            if result == None:
                print 'No result was found!'
            else:
                print " ", result**power, " ~= ", x

testFindRoot()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*\* operator TypeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675717/operator-typeerror)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After

```
result = (x, power, epsilon)
```

`result` is bound to a 3-element tuple.  So the error message is thoroughly accurate you're later trying to raise that tuple to the integer power `power`.  Python doesn't define `__pow__` for tuples, and that's all there is to it.

Presumably you *intended* to code:

```
 result = findRoot(x, power, epsilon)
```

instead.